# How can I show the bugs when I run website on browser of smart tivi

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, web, smart-tv

I have one array include clips and images. This code show clip and image, but when I have more than 2 clips, on browser of smart tivi can't show video (on browser of PC show normal). Please help me show the bugs from browser of smart tivi. Below is **index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Video</title>
    <link href="./css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</header>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <br><br>
    <div class="fullscreen-bg" id="slideshow">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is **index.js** file. When I run website in web browser of PC, it's ok, but when I run web on browser of smart tivi, it's have bugs but I can't show this. If on PC, I can turn on inspect of browser or on android mobile, I can setup to show bugs. Please help me the way show bugs from smart tivi :

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

var video_list      = ["file_upload/mov_bbb.mp4", "file_upload/Jellyfish.jpg", "file_upload/Lighthouse.jpg","file_upload/(1).mp4"];
function img(src) {
    var el = document.createElement('img');
    el.src = src;
//        el.className += "fullscreen-bg__video";
    el.style.width = "100%";
    el.style.height = "100%";
    return el;
}

function vid() {
    //Accepts any number of ‘src‘ to a same video ('.mp4', '.ogg' or '.webm')
    var el = document.createElement('video');
    el.onplay = function () {
        clearInterval(sliding);
    };
    el.onended = function () {
        sliding = setInterval(rotateimages, 5000);
        rotateimages();
    };
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        source.src = arguments[i];
        source.type = "video/" + arguments[i].split('.')[arguments[i].split('.').length - 1];
        el.appendChild(source);
    }
    el.className += "fullscreen-bg__video";
    return el;
}
var galleryarray = [];
video_list.forEach(function(item){
    if(isImage(item)){
        galleryarray.push(img(item));
    } else if(isVideo(item)){
        galleryarray.push(vid(item));
    }
});
var curimg = -1;

function rotateimages() {
    $("#slideshow").fadeOut("slow");
    setTimeout(function () {
        curimg = (curimg < galleryarray.length - 1) ? curimg + 1 : 0;
        document.getElementById('slideshow').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('slideshow').appendChild(galleryarray[curimg]);
        if (galleryarray[curimg].tagName === "VIDEO") {
            galleryarray[curimg].play();
        }
        $("#slideshow").fadeIn("slow");
    }, 1000);
}

function getExtension(filename) {
    var parts = filename.split('.');
    return parts[parts.length - 1];
}

function isImage(filename) {
    var ext = getExtension(filename);
    switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'gif':
        case 'bmp':
        case 'png':
            //etc
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isVideo(filename) {
    var ext = getExtension(filename);
    switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'm4v':
        case 'avi':
        case 'mpg':
        case 'mp4':
            // etc
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var sliding;
window.onload = function () {
    sliding = setInterval(rotateimages, 5000);
    rotateimages();

    function getExtension(filename) {
        var parts = filename.split('.');
        return parts[parts.length - 1];
    }

    function isImage(filename) {
        var ext = getExtension(filename);
        switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'gif':
            case 'bmp':
            case 'png':
                //etc
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isVideo(filename) {
        var ext = getExtension(filename);
        switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'm4v':
            case 'avi':
            case 'mpg':
            case 'mp4':
                // etc
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```